# How to create a filter in powerbi that will dynamically query the db using a SP with a parameter

Tags: powerbi, reporting

I am trying to run a direct query on my DB and apply a filter input by the user. The user input would be used as a parameter for my Stored Procedure that retrieves the data I want to display to the user. The reason for running a direct query and not just refreshing the data and then the user filtering from all of that data, is that the database is really large and it would make the report file approx. 650mb in size. My idea is that with a direct query, I can pull only the data required through an indexed column that the Stored Procedure uses to filter.

Currently I was able to create a parameter in the Query editor and use it in a query function but this creates an "Invoked Function" table. If I use these results in my report essentially the user can only filter through the result I filtered in my query editor. I want the user to be the one to input that value and the report to dynamically load it.

As far as the filter field, I am using a slicer and added the search capability to it so they can type out the search value and select the result in the list. Ideally I would like a textbox that they can type the value they want and search for it.

Is this possible in PowerBI? and if so how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download a separate application called **Power BI Report Builder** to accomplish this and create a paginated report. See Url below:

[Paginated Reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi)